# What type of freewheel remover do I need for this one

Tags: freewheel, tools

[image] this is a Louis Garneau 20inch bike wheel

Comment: If you can't find the correct tool to buy, its possible to make one by sacrificing a socket of the right diameter and spending some quality time with a hand file or grinder+cutoff wheel+grinding wheel+dunk tank.

Answer (score 3):

The 8-pin freewheel tool, as available from brick lane bikes and others, is the correct fit.

[image: tool]

Answer (score 2):

You need the one sold as "BMX" freewheel remover. Usually they have 2 or 4 prongs, the extra slots on this freewheel will just go unused.