# Which tool is required to remove an 8 notch freewheel from a single-speed flip-flop hub?

Tags: hub, freewheel, tools, flip-flop-hub

I have a single speed freewheel on a flip-flop hub that I would like to remove to service the hub. It has 8 notches, which tool do I need to remove the freewheel?

Here is a picture of it on the bike:

[image: Picture of freewheel on the bike]

Here are some pictures I found of what I assume it looks like:

[image: Found image of a similar freewheel]
[image]

Would the Park Tool FR-8 or FR-6 tool be suitable for this, or something different? Am I able to service a flip-flop hub bearings without removing the freewheel and fixed cog?

Comment: Duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90630/what-type-of-freewheel-remover-do-i-need-for-this-one/90643#90643

Comment: BLB sell this tool in the UK. I do not know if the park tool is equivalent.

Comment: Generally, but not always, bearings can be serviced without freewheel removal.

Comment: A normal BMX freewheel remover will work. The only benefit of the BLB tool is that it will not fit other brands and it’s not your benefit.

Comment: Having taken the wheel off and measured it the Park Tool FR-6 looks like it would fit and be a more useful tool than the BLB